# React: Do not render menu based on child component state

Tags: reactjs

I have a `MenuBar` that renders site-wide, so I set it up in my `App.js` like below. I want the menu to render all the time except when you visit the `HCA_Survey` link. How can I make the `MenuBar` component not render when you visit that link? There is no navigation button to that link.  It will only be visited from users clicking a link in an email, and I do not want them to have the navigation bar.

I assume I need to access it to change it from the HCA_Survey component... but I can't figure out how. Do I just need to rewrite this as a class?  I don't completely have a handle on Hooks yet.

If I change the `renderMenu` variable between true and false manually, it works as I want.  I just can't figure out how to change it to false upon visiting that link?

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [renderMenu, setMenu] = useState(true);
  function renderMenuBar(render) {
    setMenu(false);
  }
      
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        {renderMenu === true && (
          <Col xs={1}>
          <MenuBar />
        </Col>
        )}
        
        <Col className="area-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/audit" component={Audit} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/database" component={Database} />
              <Route exact path="/hca-survey/:id/:name/:level/:audit/:client" component={HCA_Survey} />
            </Switch>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `react-router-dom` you can use the `useRouteMatch` and instead re-define `renderMenu` in terms of that (whether its on that route or not).

```
const App = () => {
  const isHCASurvey = useRouteMatch("/hca-survey/:id/:name/:level/:audit/:client");

  const renderMenu = !isHCASurvey;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        {renderMenu && (
          <Col xs={1}>
          <MenuBar />
        </Col>
        )}
        
        <Col className="area-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/audit" component={Audit} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/database" component={Database} />
              <Route exact path="/hca-survey/:id/:name/:level/:audit/:client" component={HCA_Survey} />
            </Switch>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if you're not then you would need to use an effect and listen for route changes/initial render to check to see if the route for which the app is mounted on is a route where you want to hide the menu:

```
useEffect(() => {
 // modify this as needed
 const isHCASurvey = window.location.href.includes('hca-survey')
 if(isHCASurvey){
   setMenu(false)
 } else {
   setMenu(true)
 }
},[])
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am using `react-router-dom`, and this worked perfectly!